# Замена в select средством js

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, есть такой скрипт и проблема происходит в том, что при выборе предыдущего варианта, он не заменяет тут значения, а добавляет.
Пытался сделать `$("#selectf-"+ dataitemspl).empty()append(dispcity);` так он удаляет полностью, то есть с `value='0'` удаляется тоже, а необходимо его оставить и удалить только другие, ну а после соответственно будет добавляться.

```
var dataitemspl = ++dataitems;
for (var i = 0; i < infooption.length; i++) {
  var dispcity = dispcity +"<option value='"+ infooption[i] +"'>"+ infooption[i] +"</option>";
}
$("#selectf-"+ dataitemspl).append(dispcity);


<select id="selectf-2" name="selectf" data-item="2" data-name="city" style="">
<option value="0">Выберите город</option>
<option value="Аликанте">Аликанте</option>
<option value="Барселона">Барселона</option>
<option value="Мадрид">Мадрид</option>
<option value="Малага">Малага</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataitemspl = ++dataitems;

var dispcity = "";
for (var i = 0; i < infooption.length; i++) {
  dispcity = dispcity + "<option value='" + infooption[i] +"'>"+ infooption[i] + "</option>";
}
var firstItem = $("#selectf-" + dataitemspl + " option[value='0']").clone();
$("#selectf-" + dataitemspl).
  empty().
  append(firstItem).
  append(dispcity);
```

Comment: Если бы так все было просто...
Там таких select`ов 5 штук и на каждом нулевой разный

Comment: Ладно, через if сделаю по data-items